# where to start with WordPress theme development

Tags: theme-development

I recently started learning wordpress theme development and i actually find it very interesting and useful. I have basic html,css,javascript, bootstrap and php knowledge and i just watched a few tutorials and understood the basics of wordpress development such as the loop, some of the template pages and what they do, the wordpress template tags,widgets etc.

But my problem is that there are not enough FREE tutorials on the internet that i can watch and improve to a decent level. I tried to download some free themes and investigate a little bit the source code (I tried the illdy one page theme, as I'm interested in responsive one page themes with static front page) but i barely understand.

So my question is do you have any source of tutorials or a plan that i can follow? Im really interested in web development and wordpress is a very modern and useful tool that forces you to improve in all other fields(css, javascript php, etc) thats why i chose it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.org itself has it own handy guide for WordPress theme development: [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/)

You can have a great starting point there. As you move forward, you can get involve in WordPress development: [Get Involved](https://make.wordpress.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at a course like Treehouse WordPress Development with Zac Gordon. Ok its not free. it's $25 monthly. You can learn the hard way with reading and documentation but the benefit of Treehouse is a structured programme that takes you through theme development the right way.

Morten Rand Henricksen also teaches on Lynda.com and is a great teacher. I learned all the fundamentals from him.

Ok again, I know not free, but they both have a free trial period and if you look at it as a small tax deductible investment into your career, it's worth every penny. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions.

1. Firstly, learn how to use wordpress cms
2. Learn html, css, javascript
3. learn php
4. learn other wordpress developers codes ( find it from simple theme,
   don't deep into advanced themes ).
5. Make it familiar with [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/)
6. Learn from psd to wordpress converter. ( There are so many tutorials available for html to wordpress convert).
7. After you are familiar with themes, you should create a simple one by yourself.
8. Study Wordpress plugin later